# Why does $_POST data lose UTF8 characters once constructed into an object?

Tags: php, utf-8

I've been looking at lots of topics surrounding UTF8 character issues. I've confirmed that the MySQL connection and database is fine with utf characters, and found and interesting issue.

I have a form whose input field values are held by a `Class`. However, when both the `$_POST` and `Class` variables are dumped next to each other I have noticed that the class variables no longer contain the UTF8 characters.

My Class has the following constructor (I'm only pasting relevant bits, as it's a huge class):

```
public function __construct($data = array()) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['order'] ) ) $this->order = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['order'] );
    if ( isset( $data['comment'] ) ) $this->comment = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['comment'] );
}
```

The point of the constructor is to clean the input from malicious input, I've also tested the regex and it doesnt match any of the UTF8 characters that are input, and is used as `$something = new Booking($_POST)`

`$_POST` vs `Class`:

```
Postarray(17) { ["order"]=> string(18) "Külső-Belső Kárpit" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" } 

Booking obj:object(Booking)#3 (17) { ["id"]=> NULL ["order"]=> string(14) "Kls-Bels Krpit" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I read that there might be something wrong with the encoding of the class file, i'm using Atom and when checking, the encoding of the file is shown to be `UTF8`. Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the `regex` string using several online testers and that is indeed what got rid of the UTF characters - https://www.regextester.com/ shows this well.